# Require.js Module load order

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have 3 modules : Module A, Module B and Module C.

Module A writes links in my html page (the links come from an ajax async call)
Module B writes some links too. 
In my module C, I would like to add an event on the links from module A and B.

The problem is the module loading order is random.
So, when module C is loaded in first, there is no link because Module A and B didn't write yet.

Is there a way to load the module C at the end ?

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module load order *should* not matter. E.g.

#### links1.js

```
define(function() {
    return { addLinks: function() { ... } };
})
```

#### links2.js

```
define(function() {
    return { addLinks: function() { ... } };
})
```

#### events.js

```
define(function() {
    return { addEvents: function() { ... } };
})
```

#### app.js

```
require(["links1", "links2", "events"], function(links1, links2, events) {
    links1.addLinks(...);
    links2.addLinks(...);
    events.addEvents(...);
});
```

In other words, don't have your modules execute something when they load, have them return methods that can be executed when **you** are ready.

The modules above can load in any order ...

- links1, links2, events
- links1, events, links2
- links2, links1, events
- links2, events, links1
- events, links1, links2
- events, links2, links1

and it does not matter.

---

**EDIT** - If `links1` uses XHR, then `app` needs to wait for those links before adding them.

#### links1.js

```
define(function() {
    var promise = null;
    function loadLinks() {
        if (promise) {
            return promise;
        }
        return promise = $.ajax(...).then(function(data) {
            return convertDataToLinks(data);
        });
    }
    return {
        loadLinks: loadLinks,
        addLinks: function() { ... }
    };
})
```

#### app.js

```
require(["links1", "links2", "events"], function(links1, links2, events) {
    links1.loadLinks().then(function(links) {
        links1.addLinks(links);
        links2.addLinks(links);
        events.addEvents(...);
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I forget to say the links come from an ajax async call, sorry.

Comment: You might have to add more details to the question, as the above pattern does work and I use it all the time. Maybe show your module code. Maybe what you are calling modules aren't strictly AMD modules?

Comment: it works, thank you. An other solution : make synchronous ajax call